# RabbitMQ: Untouching the queue expiry upon sending

Tags: php, rabbitmq

RabbitMQ supports expiry time for queues (aka queues TTL).
[As explained in RabbitMQ documentation](http://www.rabbitmq.com/ttl.html#queue-ttl), expiry time can be pretty easily set for a given queue by setting the `x-expires` argument to `queue_declare` method.
In order to send messages , I'm declaring the queue and then push messages using the `basic_publish` method.
However, my sending code 'touches' the queue expiry - when a message is sent the expiry time resets to its initial value (30 secs in my example).

This is a simple example of how I create the queue:

```
$connection = new AMQPConnection('localhost', 5672, 'guest', 'guest');
$channel = $connection->channel();

// queueKey is given as first arg
$queueName = $argv[1];
// auto-delete the queue after x ms
$channel->queue_declare($queueName, false, true, false, false, false, 
    new AMQPTable(array("x-expires"  => 30000 )) 
);
```

And this is how I send messages:

```
$channel->queue_declare($queueName, true, true, false, false, false,
    new AMQPTable(array("x-expires"  => 30000 )));  // auto-delete the queue after x ms

// mark messages as persistent 
$msg = new AMQPMessage($data, array(
    'delivery_mode' => 2
));

// pushing the message to the queue
$channel->basic_publish($msg, '', $queueName);
```

Is there any way not touching the expiry time when sending messages? I want the expiry time to be touched only when someone is really consumed messages (i.e., there are consumers) and not upon sending. I mean, when 'someone' sends messages, I expect my 30 secs timer not to be reset.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How are you running the script that publishes messages?

> Unused means the queue […] has not been redeclared

So if you keep calling `queue_declare` in your code every time you run your producer, the timer will be reset.

You may declare the queue in a separate script and then on your producer don't issue a `queue_declare`.